# SAP HANA - Parallel Execution of Stored Procedures

Tags: stored-procedures, hana

I wanted to ask if there is a way to call the same stored procedure with a different parameter (value) either from within another stored procedure or from an xsjs-Service parallel without the use of Jobs.

From my experience so for the calls run synchronous and wait for the first call of a procedure to return before calling it the second time.

Thank you in advance for your time and help.

Kind Regards...

Answer (score 1):

SQLScript provides the option to run statements in an`PARALLEL EXECUTION` block like so:

```
DO 
  BEGIN PARALLEL EXECUTION
     INSERT INTO mytab VALUES (1, 2, 3);
     INSERT INTO myothertab VALUES (4, 5, 6);
  END;
```

See the documentation for details [here](https://help.sap.com/viewer/de2486ee947e43e684d39702027f8a94/2.0.03/en-US/8db200a4f585490c81c4930689ec1a5c.html).

**HOWEVER**: as the documentation states, this **does not** include the `CALL` statement for executing procedures.

Comment: Thank you very much. This is a feature that's only supported in Hana 2.0 right? In the 1.12 documentation it states that CALL statements are blocked within PARALLEL EXECUTION.

Comment: Just double checked and found that I was mistaken: `CALL` statements are explicitly **not** considered for parallel execution; neither in HANA 1 nor in HANA 2.

Comment: @LarsBr. could you please share some background or pointers about CALL statements not being parallelized at all despite being in PARALLEL EXECUTION block?

Comment: The [documentation](https://help.sap.com/docs/SAP_HANA_PLATFORM/de2486ee947e43e684d39702027f8a94/8db200a4f585490c81c4930689ec1a5c.html?locale=en-US) is all I can point to for that. To be honest, I never had a use for this functionality.

Answer (score 1):

Link to the documentation:
https://help.sap.com/viewer/de2486ee947e43e684d39702027f8a94/2.0.02/en-US/8db200a4f585490c81c4930689ec1a5c.html

> Restrictions and Limitations
>
> The following restrictions apply:

1. Modification of tables with a foreign key or triggers are not allowed
2. Updating the same table in different statements is not allowed
3. Only concurrent reads on one table are allowed. Implicit SELECT and
   SELCT INTO scalar variable statements are supported.
4. **Calling procedures containing dynamic SQL (for example, EXEC,
   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE) is not supported in parallel blocks**
5. Mixing read-only procedure calls and read-write procedure calls in a
   parallel block is not allowed.